# Problem with CPUPower

Tags: cpu, cpufreq, frequency

I have set my CPU frequency to min and max, but when my laptop is plugged to the adapter it changes it automatically the min and max frequency to the maximum  CPU frequency (2.2Ghz). When it is running on the battery it stays in the set frequency range. How can i solve this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
sudo cpupower frequency-set -g powersave
```

Or

```
sudo cpupower frequency-set -f 1000MHz
```

for whatever your low cpu speed might be.
I do not own a laptop so I do not know if that will do the trick.